# How to use system() in c++ to run python script containing space

Tags: python, c++, system

I wish to run a python script in c++ code but the address path contains spaces.
Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
string python = "\"D:\\my folder\\python.exe\"";
string script = "\"D:\\my scripts\\hello.py\"";
string arg = "\"argument 1\"";
string cmd= python + " " + script + " " + arg;
system(cmd.c_str());
```

Here cmd `"\"D:\\my folder\\python.exe\" \"D:\\my scripts\\hello.py\"" "\"argument 1\""`
which is in text form, expected to be executed as
"D:\my folder\python.exe" "D:\my scripts\hello.py" "argument 1" as command line,
but this fails to execute with an error ->'D:\my' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

But the same command "D:\my folder\python.exe" "D:\my scripts\hello.py" works fine in command prompt?
Please suggest in c++ how to execute python script having space in the path and pass an argument to the script.

Comment: Please check that all occurrences of `""` (i.e. two double quotes next to each other, no space in between, in your question are intentional. If yes, then I suspect the are the problem.

Comment: `system()` is a security *nightmare* and should *never* be used.

Comment: @Yunnosch string python = "\"D:\\my folder\\python.exe\" "; thre at end i can put space and avoid use
string cmd= python + script?

Comment: any alternative besides system()? which support cross-platform windows and linux @JesperJuhl

Comment: @Yunnosch i tried putting everything in single line string
like string cmd = "\"D:\\my folder\\python.exe\" \"D:\\my scripts\\hello.py\"" "\"argument 1\""; but this too fails

Comment: @Ganesh "any alternative besides system()" - Yes. `fork()` + calling one of the `exec` family of functions that actually allow you to be in control of the environment of the new process as well as its standard input, output and error streams. `system()` will just inherit the parent process environment and mash stdout and stderror into one. That can be abused and messed with in more ways than you can imagine.

Comment: If you don't might using third party libs. then you might want to have a look at [boost.process](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/process.html).

Comment: Also, if I can find the location in your executable where you call `system` (not difficult), I can probably find a way to cause that to call arbitrary shell code of my choosing.

Comment: Put single quotes around parameters with spaces or a backslash before the space `D:\My\\ dir`. See [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46621176/980129)

Comment: I don't know where will be space in path, finding and replacing I will try.
I tried single quote "\'D:\\my folder\\python.exe\'" but this doesn't work - probably i misunderstood @Manuel

Comment: `system` itself is not cross platform because it calls the system shell, and the syntax of each shell is different.

Comment: @JesperJuhl fork/exec is not cross platform.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I found a way to get it to work with a system()
I tried with exec but still had some issues there.
one needs to cover the entire command in double-quotes.

In my case it should be `"\"\"D:\\my folder\\python.exe\" \"D:\\my scripts\\hello.py\"" "\"argument 1\"\""`